# How to create graphic margin around labels in GeoServer using SLD?

Tags: sld

I have a little problem using VendorOption - graphic-margin around labels of roads. In some cases they're drawn and some places they're not. You can see it on this picture. In the square its drawn correctly but in the circle the graphic margin is missing. 
There is my code under the picture.

Any idea how to solve this?

[image: My problem]

```
<Rule>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>10000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <Name>S1p</Name>
      <Title>silnice 1. tridy paprsek</Title>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>TYPSIL_K</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>S1p</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
  <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#686868</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">4</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">1</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
  <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#FF7F7F</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">1</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
      <TextSymbolizer>
   <Label>
     <ogc:Literal>I/</ogc:Literal>
     <ogc:PropertyName>SILNICE</ogc:PropertyName>
   </Label>
   <Font>
       <CssParameter name="font-family">http://www.edpp.cz/arial.ttf</CssParameter>
       <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
       <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
       <CssParameter name="font-weight">normal</CssParameter>
   </Font>
   <Graphic>
      <Mark>
        <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
        <Fill>
      <CssParameter name="fill">#FF7F7F</CssParameter>                  
        </Fill>
      </Mark>
    </Graphic>
   <LabelPlacement>
     <LinePlacement/>
   </LabelPlacement>
   <Halo>
     <Radius>2</Radius>
     <Fill>
       <CssParameter name="fill">#FF7F7F</CssParameter>
     </Fill>
   </Halo>
   <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
   <VendorOption name="repeat">500</VendorOption>
   <VendorOption name="graphic-resize">stretch</VendorOption>                         
   <VendorOption name="graphic-margin">2</VendorOption>
 </TextSymbolizer>
</Rule>
```

Comment: is that all one image request or is it a tiled image?

Comment: I guess it's tiled image.

Comment: so could the tile on the left be a cached one from earlier attempts?

Comment: It's possible. Is there any solution?

Comment: try incognito or private mode if clearing the cache doesn't work, or you could check from another machine or post URL so we can check for you

Comment: http://www.edpp.cz/test_mapa-povodnoveho-planu-mesta/?zoom=10&lat=-1116256.5488749999&lon=-632712.5812500002&fullscreen=1&podklady=0&28=0&27=0&26=0&25=0&24=0&23=0&22=0&21=0&20=0&19=0&18=0&17=0&16=0&15=0&14=1&13=0&12=0&11=0&10=0&9=0&8=0&7=0&6=0&5=0&4=0&3=0&2=0&1=0&0=0

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything obvious wrong, comparing

[image] http://www.edpp.cz/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=test_zabaged&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A102067&STYLES=&BBOX=-635683.8400000001%2C-1115608.4479999999%2C-635171.7760000001%2C-1115096.3839999998

and

[image] http://www.edpp.cz/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng8&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=test_zabaged&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A102067&STYLES=&BBOX=-635171.7760000001%2C-1115608.4479999999%2C-634659.712%2C-1115096.3839999998

shows nor reason for one to work and not the other.

Can you file a bug report with these links at https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOS

Comment: And add a way to reproduce the issue, sample data, styles.